# Python: Using a variable inside a function (but the variable should be users input)

Tags: python, function, variables

I am trying to write a little hangman programme and I have to use this function in it (it is explicitly said in the assignment). It should check whether the guessed letter is in the word and if so, return a word consisting of *'s and guessed letter on the right position. Yet I don`t understand how can I use the "letter" variable if it is the one the user types in (his guess), so it is practically assigned outside the function. I am stuck a bit and I would be grateful if someone would say how to do it.

```
def print_guessed():
    global secret_word
    global letters_guessed
    word = []
    for i in range (0, len(secret_word)):
        if letter == secret_word[i]: word.append(letter)
        else: word.append('-')
    word_str = ''.join(word)
    return word_str
```

Comment: yuck -- who is this professor!?

Comment: My thoughts exactly. If you *have* to use this function and are not allowed to modify it, you're screwed. It will throw at least a `NameError` because `letter` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: @jedwards yuck? Nothing wrong with this question or the function beyond style. OK there's a global but most intro project use globals to simplify the problems.

Comment: @Pyrce: Really? Nothing wrong?

Comment: Don't see why you need to globalise stuff; use arguments in your function.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Well I am guessing that you're supposed to fill it in...

Comment: `letters_guessed` is "imported" but not used.  `letter` is used but not imported.  Methinks its an omission/typo in the assignment.

Comment: @Pyrce: This is horrid!  Hey...wait a minute...are you the prof?

Comment: @Gerrat Lol no. This seems like a function with some missing details and it *sounds* like the student is supposed to fix it/add the missing parts

Comment: Maybe I interpreted the problem differently than the rest of you -- I've just seen lots of intro problems with incomplete functions made that way purposefully to force students to debug/understand what the supplied functions do. I didn't mean to defend that the function works as is or state that is of the highest quality...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I f you can make change to the function, then modify an argument to it, which is the variable-`letter`.

```
def print_guessed(letter):
    #do_stuff
```

And supply the letter guessed in the call statement

```
print_guessed(letter)
```

Comment: Yup, I was just going to write that. Looks like the only way to do it to me too.

Comment: You could also iterate over the `letters_guessed` global.  eg: `for letter in letters_guessed: ...`

Comment: but letters_guessed may not be a list.  if it is, then each time the program checks for all the letters guessed from the beginning, which is time consuming

Comment: @AswinMurugesh what is it then? plural form suggests some kind of container

Comment: well, ok, it may also be some guessed-letter-count... but then again, the whole task is very ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

Actually, though I agree with the commenters that this is terribly unPythonic code, you don't actually need to modify the function to make it work. `letter` is not assigned to within the function, which means that there's no need to declare it as global there: as long as it's defined in the outer scope, it will be accessible within.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT if you're allowed to freely change the function, then just do

```
def print_guessed(letter):
    global letters_guessed
    letters_guessed.append(letter)
    return ''.join(c if c in letters_guessed else '-'
                   for c in secret_word)
```

OTHERWISE:
this is quite a tricky problem given a function that doesn't even come close to doing the right thing, but I think I've figured it out!

```
secret_word = "answer"
letters_guessed = []
letter = ''

def fix_print_guessed(func):
    def wrapper(guess):
        global letters_guessed
        global letter
        letter = guess
        letters_guessed.append(letter)
        return func()
    return wrapper


@fix_print_guessed
def print_guessed():
    global secret_word
    global letters_guessed
    word = []
    for i in range (0, len(secret_word)):
        if letter == secret_word[i]: word.append(letter)
        else: word.append('-')
    word_str = ''.join(word)
    return word_str

found = len(secret_word) * '-'
while '-' in found:
    guess = raw_input('enter a letter: ')
    res = print_guessed(guess)
    found = ''.join(c1 if c1 != '-' else c2 
                    for c1, c2 in zip(found, res))
    print found
```